# SQL avg() Incorrect

Tags: postgresql

The first table is the raw data, and the second table is the average of the numbers from the first table. The average should be 733.43, but is coming out to 760.57575. Can anyone help me understand why these numbers are different?

[image: Queries]

I know that there are other similar questions, but this is a lot simpler than those.

**Edit:**
**The following query solves my problem**

```
SELECT st.begin_ts, sum(st.count) / count(st.count) as average

FROM (
    SELECT begin_ts, process_name, avg(count) as count
    FROM ecn_stats_2019_06_18
    WHERE process_name LIKE 'matching_%_gw' and name = 'raw_msg_count' and begin_ts <= '2019-06-18 07:00:00'
    GROUP BY begin_ts, process_name) as st

GROUP BY begin_ts;
```

Comment: @muistooshort I uploaded a better quality screenshot, I didn't realize that the previous ones were bad quality

Comment: Could you please properly format your question? Please post text rather than a screenshot, explaining what you're trying to do. This will help the community answer your question

Comment: @Webber, what do you mean? My question is just wondering why the average query returns a different number than what's expected for the data displayed.

Comment: @Abelisto, but there's only one element of each process_name. I don't quite understand your point? When I manually compute the average of the first table I get 733.43, when SQL does it the avg comes out to 760.575.

Comment: @Ron Sorry, I really forget those simple formulas. Will delete my previous comment. About your question: your can simply check the correctness of the calculation by expanding your second query a bit: `select begin_ts, avg(count), sum(count), count(count), sum(count) / count(count) from ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets remember the school arithmetic. You have `avg()` in both queries and you assumes that the sum of avgs from first query divided by rows count in it will be equal to sum of actual values divided by actual rows count. Something like:

Firs query:

```
row1, (a + b) / 2
row2, (c + d + e) / 3
```

and second query, you think, should to return

```
((a + b) / 2 + (c + d + e) / 3) / 2
```

Yes? Lets expand the last expression:

```
((a + b) / 2 + (c + d + e) / 3) / 2 = (a + b) / 4 + (c + d + e) / 6 = a/4 + b/4 + c/6 + d/6 + e/6
```

But your second query actually calculates something like

```
(a + b + c + d + e) / 5 = a/5 + b/5 + c/5 + d/5 + e/5
```

which obviously is not equal to the previous one.

Example:

```
with t(a, b, c) as (values(1,1,2.0), (1,1,3.0), (1,2,4.0), (1,2,5.0), (1, 2, 6.0))
select a, avg(c) from t group by a, b;
 a |        avg         
---+--------------------
 1 | 5.0000000000000000
 1 | 2.5000000000000000
(2 rows)
```

According to the your assuming the result of query

```
with t(a, b, c) as (values(1,1,2.0), (1,1,3.0), (1,2,4.0), (1,2,5.0), (1, 2, 6.0))
select a, avg(c) from t group by a;
```

should be `(5 + 2.5) / 2 = 3.75` But it is actually is `4` (just check)